# How to subtract from certain cell in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data `date` and `a` in this table [my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJxdW.png)
How I can get `b` where the value is a subtract by `a` from previous `date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `LAG` analytic function here:

```sql
SELECT date, a, a - LAG(a) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS b
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY date;
```